# Java: Loop through Result Set for CSV file

Tags: java, jdbc

In Java, I have a query like this. In SQL, I can receive 200 records using below query

```
String sql = Select * from table1
```

Let say there are 20 columns in above table. I want to loop through the ResultSet and generate the records to the csv file. But the result I got is all the records are displayed in one row. The data don't know when to write a new records to a new row.

Here is what I have so far:

```
PreparedStatement statment = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet result = statment.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();
try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(path); 
        CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(out, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(resultSet))) {
        while(resultSet.next()) {
              for(int i = 1; i<=columnCount; i++{
                     printer.print(resultSet.getString(i));
              }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Usr `println` instead of `print` or add `+ \n` at the end of the `String`. That's why `println` is called like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that each record of each result should be print to the csv file.

But you never call [`println`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html#println--) at the end of each result on the CSV.

> public void print(Object value)
>              throws IOException
>
> Prints the string as the next value on the line.

and

> public void println()
>                throws IOException
>
> Outputs the record separator.

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
    for(int i = 1; i<=columnCount; i++{
        printer.print(resultSet.getString(i));
    }
    printer.println();
}
```